# You have an error in your SQL syntax, mysql connector for .net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

Store procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`newdb`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetMaximumIDsCount`(IN AppID INT,IN isBurnCenter INT,IN BurnCenterID INT)
BEGIN

    IF isBurnCenter = 1 THEN

    SELECT MAX(CAST(b.hospitalid AS SIGNED))

    FROM tblhosipital b

    WHERE b.appId = AppID AND b.burncenterid IS NULL;

    END IF;


    IF isBurnCenter = 0 THEN

    SELECT MAX(CAST(h.hospitalid AS SIGNED))

    FROM tblhosipital h

    WHERE h.appId = AppID AND h.burncenterid <> '' AND h.burncenterid = BurnCenterID;

    END IF;
END
```

Calling from ApplicationDbContext (code first)

```
public virtual ObjectResult<long?> GetMaximumIDsCount2(Nullable<int> appID, Nullable<int> isBurnCenter, Nullable<int> burnCenterID)
        {
            var appIDParameter = appID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("AppID", appID) :
                new ObjectParameter("AppID", typeof(int));

            var isBurnCenterParameter = isBurnCenter.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("isBurnCenter", isBurnCenter) :
                new ObjectParameter("isBurnCenter", typeof(int));

            var burnCenterIDParameter = burnCenterID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("BurnCenterID", burnCenterID) :
                new ObjectParameter("BurnCenterID", typeof(int));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Nullable<long>>("GetMaximumIDsCount @AppID, @isBurnCenter, @BurnCenterID", appIDParameter, isBurnCenterParameter, burnCenterIDParameter);
        }
```

Getting exception:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'GetMaximumIDsCount @AppID, @isBurnCenter, @BurnCenterID' at line
>   1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `CALL [procedure_name]()` method before stored procedure name:

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this)
       .ObjectContext
       .ExecuteStoreQuery<List<long?>>("CALL GetMaximumIDsCount(@AppID, @isBurnCenter, @BurnCenterID)", 
       appIDParameter, isBurnCenterParameter, burnCenterIDParameter);
```

**Note:** MySQL stored procedure executed with this syntax:

```
CALL procedure_name(parameter_list)
```

**Note 2:** Use `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` to return exactly one result set from `ObjectResult<T>`:

```
var x = db.GetMaximumIDsCount2(...).FirstOrDefault();
```

As a side note, you can try declaring parameters with `MySqlParameter` instead of `ObjectParameter`:

```
// you can change DBNull.Value with any appropriate value

var appIDParameter = new MySqlParameter("AppID", MySqlDbType.Int).Value = (appID.HasValue) ? appID : DBNull.Value;

var isBurnCenterParameter = new MySqlParameter("isBurnCenter", MySqlDbType.Int).Value = (isBurnCenter.HasValue) ? isBurnCenter : DBNull.Value;

var isBurnCenterParameter = new MySqlParameter("BurnCenterID", MySqlDbType.Int).Value = (burnCenterID.HasValue) ? burnCenterID : DBNull.Value;
```

Reference:

[CALL Syntax (MySQL)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html)

Comment: I added `CALL` before procedure name, now I'm getting exception `The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.` (both if statements in procedure are returning integer)

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` after method name to return exactly one result set from `ObjectResult`.